# Using google map api(javascript) with django queryset, I can't access queries well of the queryset

Tags: javascript, python, django

I can't access queries of queryset. Only, I can have the first query of queryset, if I do like this.

### views.py

```
def restaurant(request, pk):
    restaurants = Restaurant.objects.all()
    ctx = {
        'restaurants’: restaurants
    }
    return render(request, 'base_app/restaurant.html', ctx)
```

### base.html

```
    var markers =[];

    // new map
    var map = new
    google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    {% for restaurant in restaurants %}
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {{ restaurant.locate }},
            map: map,
        });

        var restaurant_introduction =
            '<div class="restaurant_set">\n' +
            ' <div class="restaurant_image"></div>\n' +
            ' <div class="restaurant_content">\n' +
            '   <div class="restaurant_name">{{ restaurant }}</div>\n' +
            ' </div>\n' +
            ' <a href="{% url "base_app:restaurant" pk=restaurant.pk %}"><div class="comments">more</div></a>\n' +
            '</div>';

        markers.push(marker);
    {% endfor %}
}
```

Do I have to use Json?? OR what should I do to use other queries(I mean other restaurants, not only first one).

Answer (score 0):

Within your view, you're only passing 'comments' as context, but you're calling 'restaurants' in your html. If you want to call 'restaurants' in your html, you have to pass it in as context within your view first.

You need to assign some value to restaurants (likely a queryset), and then define your context like this

ctx = { 'comments': comments,
        'restaurants': restaurants,
 }

Comment: It was just type error, when I edit it to upload here. Anyway, thank you for correcting! :)